# Make TaskCompletionSource<T>.Task run in background from asp.net mvc request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, taskcompletionsource

In one action of my MVC 4 apps, I have a call:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
   DownloadAsync("uri","file path");
   return Content("OK");
}
```

`DownloadAsync` return a Task and I expect to see the `DownloadAsync` run in background. But I always see that MVC only response when the `Task` of `DownloadAsync` is completed (means that need wait for download complete before response). If I wrap the async call in to `Task.Run()` or `Task.Factory.StartNew()`, then it works as my expectation. Here's method `DownloadAsync`:

```
private Task DownloadAsync(string url, string originalFile)
{
    var tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

    var client = new WebClient();
    AsyncCompletedEventHandler completedHandler = null;
    completedHandler = (s, e) =>
    {
        var wc = (WebClient)s;
        wc.DownloadFileCompleted -= completedHandler;

        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            tsc.TrySetCanceled();
        }
        else if (e.Error != null)
        {
            tsc.TrySetException(e.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            tsc.SetResult(true);
        }
        wc.Dispose();
    };
    client.DownloadFileCompleted += completedHandler;
    client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), originalFile);

    return tsc.Task;
}
```

So my question are:

1. Why MVC request need wait for complete Task in this case? Is there any special for `Task` created by `TaskCompletionSource<T>`?
2. How to make the `Task` of `DownloadAsync` run in background without pause the response of MVC request?

Thanks,

Comment: On which line is execution blocking?

Comment: @Snixtor: `return Content("OK");` runs, but MVC does not response. I can see 'OK' in web browser only after download is completed (file is saved).

Comment: Do you have access to .NET 4.5? if so you can use `WebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync` which will greatly simplify your code.

Comment: No, I don't. Currently I wrap call to `Task.Factory.StartNew()` as a workaround.